# How do I use/read an api documentation to send a simple request?

Tags: api, postman

I know this is probably strictly case-specific, but I do feel like I encounter this problem a lot so I will make an effort to try and understand it better.

I am new to using APIs, but I have never succeeded in using one without copying someone's code. In this case, I can't even find any examples on forums, nor in the API documentation.

I'm trying to pull my balance value from my investment bank "NordNet" to scroll, amongst other things, on an Arduino display I've made. Right now I use python Selenium to automatically but "physically" login to NordNet and grab my balance from the DOM. As I'm afraid I might get "punished" for such botted behavior, and because the script is fairly high maintenance (as the HTML changes over time), I would obviously much rather get this information through NordNet's new API.

---

[Link to NordNets API doc](https://www.nordnet.se/externalapi/docs/api)

Every time I try to utilize an API doc it's always the same, it looks easy, but I can never get it to work.

This time I tried to just play a little with the API before exploring further.
I use PostMan to send the simplest request:

https://www.nordnet.se/api/2

And I get a successful code 200 JSON response.

I then try to take it a step further to access my account data using this endpoint:

https://www.nordnet.se/api/2/accounts

For this one, I obviously need some authentication of some sort

The doc looks like this:

[image]

So I set my PostMan client up like this and get the response showcased:

[image]

I've put my NordNet login into the "Auth" tab as "basic auth" and I then see PostMan encrypts this info some way, in the "Headers" tab.

---

I'm getting an unauthorized response code and I have no idea why. Am I using PostMan wrong (probably)? Is the API faulty (probably not)? There is a mention of a `session_id` that should contain both password and username? Maybe something completely else...

I hope you can help

Comment: So, how did this turn out? did you find out which session id to use?

Comment: You have to call "/login" and authenticate before calling "/accounts". Did you get it to work, since I am also facing the same issues calling "/login" ?.

Comment: Also stuck on authentication. I would like to fetch the winners and losers from the frontpage.  https://www.nordnet.fi/api/2/instrument_search/query/winnerslosers?exchange_list=fi&limit=7

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says to use session_id as username and password for that api ,

so try logging in and then get the session id (try with both sid and ssid) . from network tab and pass it as username and password for authorization .

sid- is for http and ssid for https i guess , try with both

[image]